# Docker volumes in Multiple layers of docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration

We have our builds running inside a docker container for our continuous-integration.
Inside this container we pull down come code and run some tests, for some of these tests we need to run docker-compose with config being copied into the specified containers.

we have this structure

```
Host {
    dockerAgent {
        - has files in a folder on the file system
        - runs docker compose
    }
}
```

The `dockerAgent` runs `docker-compose` and needs to copy files into the created

```
service-name:
    container_name: ${Container}
    image: ${image}
    volumes:
        - ./sourceFolder:/opt/destinationFolder
    command:
        - "command that triggers something"
```

Due to the nested docker containers, docker is trying to copy `sourceFolder` from the `Host` and not from `dockerAgent` does anyone know how to get docker to look in `dockerAgent` instead?